# Apply header height to body as padding top on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm able to fetch and applying the `height` of the `header` as `padding top` to `body`on `window.resize`. the issue is when i tried to resize the `window` to full width the `resize` function is not working i think.

```js
var headerHeight = $('header').innerHeight();
console.log(headerHeight);
function carouselHeight(){
 $('body').removeAttr('style');
 $('body').css("padding-top", headerHeight);
};
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 carouselHeight();    
});
$(window).resize(function(){
 carouselHeight();
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Why Bootstrap</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Why Bootstrap</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Navbar example</h1>
        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
        <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: seems a really convoluted way of altering the padding on the body based on the size of hte screen. Better to have CSS media queries do the heavy lifting for you: you know what the padding needs to be for each viewport size. Simply make a media query that applies a different padding for each viewport size. And also note that in the deleting of the style attribute - you are deleteing all of the CSS for that element - eg min height as well as the top padding.

Comment: What is ```header``` which you are trying to use in your selector?

Comment: @gavgrif yes, we can manage it through media queries also. but at one stage it wont work definitely. So i preferred script;

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I found the mistake in my `script`. Header height is not mentioned in the function. so it is not getting the correct height in on resize

```
function carouselHeight(){
    var headerHeight = $('header').innerHeight();
    $('body').removeAttr('style');
    $('body').css("padding-top", headerHeight);
    console.log(headerHeight);
    console.log('hi');
};
$(document).ready(carouselHeight);
$(window).resize(carouselHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute them like this:

```
var headerHeight = $('header').innerHeight();
console.log(headerHeight);
function carouselHeight(){
    $('body').removeAttr('style');
    $('body').css("padding-top", headerHeight);
};

 $(document).ready(carouselHeight);
 $(window).resize(carouselHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks you @kittyCat. Issue is the headerHeight need to place in side carouselHeight function.